# Is there a way to get the last /dev/sd device connected using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Say I have 2 storage devices, `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` (hard and ssd). After connecting another storage device, with unknown name, I want to to get and print the name that was attributed to it (`/dev/sdc`/ for example). Is there any way to do this in a simple way? I wanted to do this with the more difficult (and inefficient) route of comparing the outputs of 2 `lsblk` commands that were run before and after the device connection. Worth noting is that I do not have experience working with bash and a project I'm working on requires me to run a script automatically after a storage device was connected.

Comment: If you have a tool which waits for a storage connection, then your way is okay. Although I think, you do not need lsblk, also a `cat /proc/partitions` is enough. But, if you want to run this thing permanently, and you want to call a script for all newly connected storage, I think you want [udev](https://opensource.com/article/18/11/udev). https://unix.stackexchange.com is full with linux/udev gurus, this stackoverflow is mostly for developers.

Comment: Thank you @peterh, I'm a developer myself so I'm used to coming here for my answer. Will try to the unix stack exchange then.

Comment: One way (brutal?) is to analyze dmesg(1) output. When a device is plugged, the log records everything (more or less) the kernel does. Plug a device, then type `dmesg`. Look at the last lines...

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked before. You can get help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422500/how-do-you-swap-dev-sda-with-dev-sdb) guide.

I suggest that if you are new and do not need to do this, do not do it

Comment: I just need to get the name so I can pass it as an argument to a second script. I'm not trying to go into specifics like partitions, udev rules, etc.

Comment: udev rules are how you tell the operating system to call your script when a device is connected or disconnected. They're a very important specific. :)